Is it possible to have an inline-definition of a dataclass in Python?
Preliminary note: The first three examples provided all work. My question is: If I declare dataclasses that are only used once inside another dataclass, can I avoid the "proper" declaration of the nested dataclass in favour of an "inline" declaration?
I want to use nested dataclasses because it makes attribute access in my IDE simpler, i.e. I want to be able to use dot notation like MyNestedDataclass. and my IDE will suggest group_1 and group_2.

I want to define a nested dict and make use of Dataclass's feature for dot-notation - mainly because my type checker then suggests the fields. This is the data structure I aim for:
my_nested_dict = {
    "group_1": {
        "variable_1a":10,
        "variable_1b":True,
    },
    "group_2": {
        "variable_2a":"foo",
    }
}

Currently, I am doing this:
@dataclass
class Group1:
    variable_1a: int = 10
    variable_1b: bool = True

@dataclass
class Group2:
    variable_2a: str = "foo"

@dataclass
class MyNestedDataclass:
    group_1: Group1
    group_2: Group2

I have tried this pattern, but it leads to my type checker not knowing which keys should be allowed in MyNestedDataclass.group_1 and MyNestedDataclass.group2, and me not being able to access it like MyNestedDataclass.group_1.variable_1a:
@dataclass
class MyNestedDataclass:
    group_1: dict[str, Any] = field(default_factory=lambda:{
        "variable_1a":10,
        "variable_1b":True,
    })
    group_2: field(default_factory=lambda:{
        "variable_2a":"foo",
    })

It seems very unlikely, but is there something like this:
@dataclass
class MyNestedDataclass:
    group_1: Group1 = field(default_factory=lambda: dataclass(
        variable_1a: int = 10
        variable_1b: bool = True
    ))

    group_2: Group2= field(default_factory=lambda: dataclass(
        variable_2a: str = "foo"
    ))


Your initial solution works for me in VS Code with pylance.  What type checker are you running, and what is the error?

Yes, the first three solutions all work. However, I would like my editor (I use VSCode) to be able to suggest to me what keys are in the object such that when I type my_nested_dataclass.g, the options .group_1 and .group_2 show up. This question is not about correct or wrong code, but about using the convenient suggestion feature of many editors.

And for the type checker: I would like my type checker to know that doing my_nested_dataclass.group_1 = "bar" is not correct, because the type of my_nested_dataclass.group_1 is int.

Have you tried just group_1: Group1 = field(default_factory=Group1) ?  I don't see why you need an inline definition of the dataclasses

What is wrong with your "currently I am doing this" code?  Your subsequent attempts seem related to providing default values, e.g. so you can instantiate without passing groups like my_nested_dataclass() ...is that what you are trying to solve?

in comments you talk about doing my_nested_dataclass.group_1 = "bar" but are you aware you need to instantiate the dataclass?  It would help if you named the class in CamelCase according to Python conventions, then it's clearer that you don't have an instance.

Yes, I am aware I need to instantiate the dataclass. Yes, I am aware that my current code is working. This question is purely about whether I can avoid declaring a dataclass that I only use once, and instead declare it inline. I will specify the question accordingly.


Is it possible to have an inline-definition of a dataclass in Python?

Short answer: No, not at type-checking time.
It is possible to create a class, and thus a dataclass, at runtime with type():
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> C = dataclass(type('C', (), {'__annotations__': {'a': int, 'b': str}, 'a': 0, 'b': 'lorem'}))
>>> help(C.__init__)
Help on function __init__ in module __main__:

__init__(self, a: int = 0, b: str = 'lorem') -> None
    Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.

However, the specification doesn't require type checkers to support it. In fact, it only ever mentions the class-based syntax.
A type checker (in your case, Pyright) might or might not choose to add this extra support. You can open a feature request, but such a request is likely to be rejected, in my experience.
